# Set the active item in a custom group list component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

**EDIT** Here is a codepen of my current component:
https://codepen.io/Gecko29/pen/XWdZPpj

I am trying to use the vuetify list component to create a folder like structure in my application. I have an object like so:

```
listOfItems = {item1 : {
                          expanded = true,
                          subList = [item, item...]
                       },
               item2 : {....
```

My current code to display each parent item along with the sublist items can be found here:

https://codepen.io/Gecko29/pen/XWdZPpj

This works with the list displayed and being able to toggle the hiding and showing of containing list items.

I now wish to be able to set a sublist item as being active. To do this I have a variable that stores the active sublist name. If containingItem == activeItem, I wish for this item to be highlighted as if it were selected. What would be the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Just a suggestion: for folder-like components, you might want to take a look at [vuetify's treeview](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview/#treeview).

Comment: Thanks for the sugggestion, I think for flexibility my custom list component suits my application better

Answer (score 0):

The simplest one is that you can wrap {{containingItem}} value inside a div or a span. Then check the condition to add the active class or not to that div. For example, I check containingItem equal "x":

```
    <v-list-item-subtitle>
         <div :class="containingItem === 'x'? 'active': ''">{{containingItem}}</div>
    </v-list-item-subtitle>
```

Comment: Hi, I see how that would set the active class but how would I be able to see the selected colour like in these examples: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/list-item-groups/

Comment: if you want it likes the sample:
1. you have to add an active variable for each subItem, when you click, set active = true.
2. add condition, subItem.active == true => add class.
3. write a css class to make the background has a color when you select.
I am not sure what you want, but if it's all that you need, please think proactively